# Generating a perfect maze in C

Tags: c, maze

I want to be able to generate a perfect maze in a file (in C). The maze itself will be represented like such:

```
**XX**X*
X**X****
XX*X*XX*
XX***XX*
```

Meaning that the X are walls and the '*' are empty spaces (where you can move).

What I have done for now is: generate a block of 'X' and its size if chosen by the user at launch.

Example :

```
./maze 10 5
```

Would generate :

```
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
```

And all I have to do now is implement my algorithm.

But sadly, from the many algorithms I have found to generate a perfect maze, most of them are drawn with walls being as you would imagine them, and not a character in a file, so I don't know how to implement it in this case.

My main source being :

http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-algorithms-to-generate-a-random-maze

Can you guys tell me how I could implement such thing with my particular case?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Any code you tried so far?

Comment: There are two parts in your problem : first, adapt an algorithm to work with walls as cells instead of borders. Then implement it to represent each cell with a character. Anyway, your question as-is is not focused enough for SO, so please try implementing something and come back if you encounter a code-related problem.

Comment: Of course, I understand, I should always come with something to show, but I mostly wanted some advice and ideas. I'll come back later with some work. Thank you.

Comment: [First hit on google](http://www.mazeworks.com/mazegen/mazetut/)

Comment: I've read this many times, but my problem comes from the way I have to display the maze (a file where walls are considered as one character)

Comment: @Aruixe You should first get up to the point where you have a 2D array in memory containing your walls and spaces. *Then* focus on translating this array into characters. Where are you at ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the algorithms you linked will work if you expand each cell into 4 cells, and use the top, left and top left as the walls if they exist.

Walls below the cell will be handle as a wall above the cell below, if that makes sense?